# Delete CTE with where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table name `Queue_Demo`

```
SnipID  UserID
AAQXFU  179
AAQXFU  161
AAQXFU  164
AATEGD  161
AATEGD  164
AATEGD  179
AATSIE  179
AATSIE  161
AATSIE  164
```

If `UserID` eg. `179` comes and ask for `SnipID` he will get `AAQXFU`
So from the `Queue_Demo` table that `SnipID` should be deleted.

My `Get` method

```
set nocount on;
with cte as (
    select top(1) SnipID
    from dbDataEntry.Queue_Demo  with (rowlock, readpast)
    where UserID =179 
    order by SnipID
)
delete from cte
output deleted.SnipID;
```

This method only deletes one row with `UserID` `179`.
But the other row with `AAQXFU` are still there.

**EDIT:**
What I want. Is to delete every record from `AAQXFU`

Comment: Are you asking a question or ? You only delete one row because you have select top 1 - Remove that and you will get all deleted by userid 179

Comment: @Thomas, if I remove top(1) that UserID 179 gets deleted from the table. 
But `AAQXFU` still remain.

Comment: So what is your problem? If you want a specific snipid to be deleted you need to write the logic behind that? Cause otherwise it makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this also

```
set nocount on;
with cte as (
    select top(1) SnipID
    from dbDataEntry.Queue_Demo with (rowlock, readpast)
    where UserID =179 
    order by SnipID
)

delete  a output DELETED.snipid from dbDataEntry.Queue_Demo a 
inner join cte b on a.snipid = b.snipid
```

**EDIT** - Added output to query

Comment: How do I write OUTPUT command on this, because I need to return with a SnipID

Answer (score 1):

Using your test data, this deletes all rows where SnipID equals AAQXFU

```
DELETE FROM dbDataEntry.Queue_Demo 
OUTPUT DELETED.SnipID
WHERE
   SnipID = (SELECT min(SnipID) FROM dbDataEntry.Queue_Demo WHERE UserID = 179)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems want `row_number()` function :

```
delete t
from (select *, row_number () over (partition by userid order by snipid) as seq
      from dbDataEntry.Queue_Demo
     ) t
where t.userid = 179 and
      seq > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE a FROM dbDataEntry.Queue_Demo a
WHERE 
 EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbDataEntry.Queue_Demo WHERE UserId = 179 AND SnipID = a.SnipID)
```